# component is defined but never used no-unused-vars error warning in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, eslint

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import navBar from "./components/navBar/navBar"; //navBar is imported here

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <navBar /> //navBar is used here
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I changed the eslint. But no use and tried some stackoverflow solutions but no change.

Answer (score 2):

In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags.

So you can change the component name to NavBar, or while importing you can write `import NavBar from "./components/navBar/navBar"; //navBar is imported here`

Comment: It workerd thanks for the information I did'nt know that. In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags.